# Counters and jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a counter running on one of my add input jquery functions:

```
 var i = $(".title").size() +1;
```

so this will result in ids of title1, title 2, title3, and etc.
I was wondering how I can call i into my selector for a function that I am appending to the first function:

```
$('#title').val(ui.item.title);
```

Essentially, I would like something that says "'#title'+i"  (yes, i know this isn't the correct way)

I've looked at this list of selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

would something like the Multiple Attribute Selector work or the `:eq()` Selector??

Comment: What's wrong with doing `$("#title" + i)`?

Comment: Does the actual code contain selectors like `$(['#title'])`? That's not right, it should be just `$('#title')`.

Comment: i just fixed it!  I was playing around with all the different selectors and left the [] in there.   since ("#title" + i) is supposed to work (thanks for letting me know!) and isn't working for me now, i'm guessing the i isn't being called.  will fiddle around with it some more and see if i can pinpoint the problem somehow.

Comment: i'm a moron!  it worked after i used a different selector for the counter. I was about to give up after hours of hairpulling, but your responses encouraged me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I fully grasp the problem. If `i` is `3` and you want to select the element with ID `title3` then `$('#title'+i)` will definitely work.

Do you want the [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector)?

```
$('input[id^=title]')
```

will select all `<input>` elements which have an ID that starts with `title`.

Perhaps you want to select the `i`<sup>th</sup> element id class `title`?

```
$('.title:eq(' + i + ')')
```

Comment: +1, but, from [the API](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector): '**value** An attribute value. Quotes are mandatory.'

Comment: @David I know what the API says. Try it yourself. Many cases will work without the quotes. If you look at the source, you'll see that the regexp (`*gasp*`) used for attribute selectors allows both.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but thanks for the information; it's just that if the API states something is mandatory I infer that the underlying regex might, at some point, be changed to remove the non-quoted use. Plus, to be fair, I'm being just a tad pernickety because the API said so.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this isn't exactly what you asked for, but have you considered just assigning a title class to each of these and using that for your selector?